# C++ write a parquet file with parquet::StreamWriter

Tags: c++, parquet, apache-arrow

I am trying to write a parquet file with some fake data. The [documentation](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/parquet.html) is not very clear on the types to be used with the out stream: it iterates over a non-specified data structure and access its methods.

The following code gets as an exception:

```
std::shared_ptr<arrow::Field> field_a, field_b;
field_a = arrow::field("A", arrow::int32());
field_b = arrow::field("B", arrow::float64());

std::shared_ptr<arrow::Schema> schema;
schema = arrow::schema({field_a, field_b});

std::shared_ptr<arrow::io::FileOutputStream> outfile;
std::shared_ptr<WriterProperties> props =
        WriterProperties::Builder().compression(arrow::Compression::SNAPPY)->build();

std::string path2_to_file{"..."};
auto result = arrow::io::FileOutputStream::Open(path2_to_file);
if (result.ok())
{
    std::cout<<"opening file\n";
    outfile = result.ValueOrDie();
}
else{
    std::cout<<"Result not ok\n";
}
std::shared_ptr<parquet::SchemaDescriptor> parquet_schema;
parquet::arrow::ToParquetSchema(schema.get(), *props, &parquet_schema);

std::shared_ptr<parquet::schema::GroupNode> group_nodes(const_cast<parquet::schema::GroupNode *>(parquet_schema->group_node()));
parquet::StreamWriter os{
  parquet::ParquetFileWriter::Open(
    outfile, 
    group_nodes,
    props)};
int i = 0;
std::cout<<schema->ToString()<<std::endl;
while(i<3)
{
  os<<int32_t{12}<<double(10.4)<<parquet::EndRow;
  i++;
}
```

> terminate called after throwing an instance of
> 'parquet::ParquetException'   what():  Column converted type mismatch.
> Column 'A' has converted type[NONE] not 'INT_32'

From the error it seems to expect a `[NONE]` type, whatever that means, not an int32. But if I try to pass a float to the first column the error changes:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of
> 'parquet::ParquetException'   what():  Column physical type mismatch.
> Column 'A' has physical type 'INT32' not 'DOUBLE'

However, if I define the schema only with the `float64` and pass to the stream writer a double, everything works fine.

How to pass data to be written to the `Parquet::StreamWriter` object?